# How do I add MVC Areas and Web API to an existing Asp.net MVC 4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-areas

We've been building an MVC 4 application for a couple of months which has grown quite a bit. It's gotten quite messy in that we're finding a lot of calls to Controller actions to return JSON data instead of Views.

To clean this up we want to do two things:

1. Add MVC areas
2. Add a Web API for all AJAX/JSON type calls

### Problems

1. I just discovered that WebAPI doesn't support areas
   Even this custom approach seems like there's just one too many potential drawbacks: http://blogs.infosupport.com/asp-net-mvc-4-rc-getting-webapi-and-areas-to-play-nicely/

The reason Areas make sense is because you can add controllers per area of your API as follows:
API
----AdminController
----ProfileController
----TransactionsController

So the rest of your areas would deal with standard MVC controllers, actions and views, but the API area would deal specifically with API calls.

This seems like it should have been straight forward?

Answer (score 0):

Why not put your Web API in a separate project in the same solution and avoid bloating your MVC project further. You can then add areas to your MVC project and avoid any side effects on your API stuff. You may then need to factor out a separate data access project that both projects would share.

Comment: thanks @jksemple. What does this do for security though? How do I carry the authentication/authorisation across to the WebAPI project?

Comment: Good point. We are doing auth explicitly in our API project because it is accessed directly from a client rather than in the context of an existing authenticated Web session. Not sure whether a separate Web API project would work for you.